# Menu Button not showing on Action Bar

Tags: android, menu, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-actionbar

I have an application running on Honeycomb that uses an Action Bar. On an XLarge emulator the Action Bar appears as documented with an icon, application name on the left and a menu dropdown on the right. If however I run this on an emulator that is smaller that XLarge e.g. Large or Normal, I do not get the menu dropdown on the Action Bar. Menu is therefore only available by use of the PgUp key. Anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: Apologies but what code is required? The problem appears to be down to the Emulated device screen size, exactly the same application is being used. The issue is that on emulators smaller than XLarge I do not get the menu drop down in Action Bar.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to first thoroughly review the [Dev Guide on Action Bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html).  I suspect that your problem is that the behavior you are getting may relate to the the sdk level set for the different virtual devices you are using.  Try it with two virtual devices that are set up with differing display resolutions/sizes *but that are using the same sdk level*.  You should get similar same behavior.

[This post in the Android Developers blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+blogspot%2FhsDu+%28Android+Developers+Blog%29) has a good discussion of the design transition from the old *Menu Button* to use of the new *Action Bar* and *Action Overflow* list.